# incompatible types port Bluemix JAVA SQL

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've been trying to connect SQL on BlueMix for a while. 
I'm getting the error on:

`port = ((int) obj.get("port"));`

Incompatible types.

I copied the code from the demo supplied:
https://hub.jazz.net/project/pvanrun/SQLDBJava/overview

I tried to flip it around to:

```
port = Integer.valueOf((String) obj.get("port"));
```

However, I get this error:

```
Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.callcenter.data.SQLDatabase.processVCAP:144'
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.String
at com.ibm.callcenter.data.SQLDatabase.processVCAP(SQLDatabase.java:144)
at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspService(_index.java:98)
at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
at [internal classes]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you posting a question. Please post all of you code on SO rather than linking to a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a similar question has been asked on developerWorks here:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/20560/issue-connecting-to-sqldb-service-instance-from-java-struts-app.html

Port is an integer. Try change

```
 port = (String) obj.get("port");
```

to Integer

```
 port = (Integer) obj.get ("port");
```

Or use the 'jdbcurl' attribute inside the SQLDB VCAP services:

```
 connectionUrl = (String) obj.get("jdbcurl");
```